# A generic error occurred in GDI+ when viewing a 1200 Dpi Tiff Image

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gdi+, tiff

I have created a tiff viewer and it can already view tiff images. Except when it is at a high resolution like 1200 DPI. Is there any workaround in my code that is causing the problem?

```
 Public Function GetTiffImage(path As String, page As Integer) As Image


        Dim ms As MemoryStream = Nothing
        Dim SrcImg As Image = Nothing
        Dim returnImage As Image = Nothing

        Try
            SrcImg = Image.FromFile(path)
            ms = New MemoryStream()
            Dim FrDim As New FrameDimension(SrcImg.FrameDimensionsList(0))
            SrcImg.SelectActiveFrame(FrDim, Page)
            SrcImg.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Tiff)
            returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        Finally
            SrcImg.Dispose()
            GC.Collect()
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        End Try

        Return returnImage
    End Function
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In my experience this error message is misleading and it's usually caused by an `OutOfMemoryException`. I'd wager that you're losing memory because you're failing to clean up all of your `IDisposable` objects. I understand that `GC.Collect()` isn't necessarily a reliable approach. Try putting some `using` blocks in. I use C# not VBScript so can't give you the exact syntax but in C# it'd be something like this:

```
using (var SrcImg = Image.FromFile(path))
{
  using (var ms = MemoryStream())
  {
    var FrDim = new FrameDimension(SrcImg.FrameDimensionsList(0));
    SrcImg.SelectActiveFrame(FrDim, Page)
    SrcImg.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Tiff)
    using (var returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms))
    {
      return returnImage;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have converted it to vb.net but still the GDI+ error occurs, the tiff file is very big (250MB)

Answer (score 0):

Memory that processing images need to release after function to prevent memory leak.
This sampel code based on your code has been modify to prevent memory leak.

```
Public Function GetTiffImage(path As String, page As Integer) As Image
    Using ms As New MemoryStream
        Using SrcImg As Image = Image.FromFile(path)
            Using returnImage As Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
                Try
                    Dim FrDim As New FrameDimension(SrcImg.FrameDimensionsList(0))
                    SrcImg.SelectActiveFrame(FrDim, page)
                    SrcImg.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Tiff)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Throw ex
                End Try
                Return returnImage
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: A short summary would help reviewers (like me) to judge the validity of your answer; interested users wouldn't have to dive into the code to understand your approach. Just a sentence or two would be fine and not too much work.